# Getting "Assertion failed on expression" error when unloading scene in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene, addressables

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
Assertion failed on expression: 'offsetIndex != -1'


Assertion failed on expression: 'offsetIndex != -1'UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&
```

I'm using SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync then loading a scene right after. This actually works perfectly, but it still throws these errors :( So it's very strange. Actually throws that second error 15 times.

I'm using basically the same script as the SceneLoader in this example project from Unity: https://github.com/UnityTechnologies/open-project-1

Has anybody run into this before? I have no idea what to do. Been very frustrating.

Comment: It's actually a bug occurred to me sometime before too for me it just got fixed by deleting the library folder in the project and letting unity create another one on startup
just make sure to create a backup

Comment: @PixelParas I actually did delete the Library folder, but it didn't end up doing anything sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, it was caused by `LightProbes.TetrahedralizeAsync()`, don't know why, but switching to `LightProbes.Tetrahedralize()` fixed it.